# Difference between Content Grouping and Custom Dimension in Google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Using custom dimension, all the content grouping features can be achieved. Is there any special need for content grouping?

Answer (score 2):

There are [dedicated dimensions and metrics available](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=content_grouping) to you if you use content grouping. And since custom dimensions are limited they can be freed up for other uses. With content grouping you can do interesting things like querying both `ga:previousContentGroupXX` and `ga:contentGroupXX` and get sense of the path taken from one content group to another.

I would be interested in how you achieved these features with only custom dimensions; are you using [Content Data Import](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtDataImport#content) or are you sending all the information with [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/)?

Comment: Thanks Matt. I didn't know about the dedicated metrics and dimensions. Now it makes sense.